# Styling bug on "Your Answer" Toolbar

Tags: bug, design, editor, firefox

The help icon in the toolbar for answering a question looks like it's in the wrong position.

Firefox 42.0 Windows 10, couldn't replicate in other browsers.

It appears on multiple communities.

Stack Overflow
[image: bug]

Meta
[image: bug2]